# Guest OS daemon failed. Any idea why?

Tags: 11.10, vmware, services

I am running a guest Ubuntu 11.10 on top of a host Windows OS. When installing the VMware tool set, somehow the execution is aborted.

I realized that the Guest operating system daemon failed to start. Anyone knows why this might be happening?

Thanks

http://pastebin.com/xHrkDKdE for the log.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 3.0 or Linux kernel 3.0? there is a difference...

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10, and Linux 3.0.0.12. Why?

Comment: Ubuntu 3.0 isn't the same as Linux 3.0...

Comment: Linux 3.0.0.12 is the kernel not the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seemed familiar and I saw a post in vmware comunities about having open-vm-tools installed already. Could you check if you have them, then uninstall and try recompiling vmware-tools?

```
sudo dpkg --search open-vm-tools
sudo apt-get purge open-vm-tools
```

Edit: I enclosed this as a comment in another question @Peretz made related to this one and this solved it.